# ECM - Document Control Management / Versioning and CMS

Tags: php, version-control, content-management-system, versioning, ecm

I anticipate this is going to be a very broad question however I shall endevour to be as concise as possible without divulging too much project critical information.

For quite some time I have been working a Content Management System. However, its vastly different to many CMS's available because of the way it handles the dispatch of requests over a server pool and incorporates its own Template Engine which I developed speciffically with flexibility and ease of use in mind.

Any way, this is completed and I'm happy.

Looking over my product, I'm seeing lots of practical applications for such a product. However for my target audience to be reached I need to expand on several of the core features which I currently offer.

Namely, I want to provide a solid document management system and include sharing and versioning of documents to enable businesses to pretty much use the product as an Enterprise Content Management Solution.

I am trying to find if there are first any 'plug' in document control solutions available on licence. After researching SharePoint I can see that its not really the 'plug' in type of thing I'm looking for as I would need to take a massive step BACK to refactor lots of the site.

The site is coded in PHP and runs several Java apps in the back end also currently so code/language divergence is not an issue. I run accross a mySQL database currently however can support (again) other types of RDMS.

If you have created a website, which creates websites, how would you handle the additional features that a ECM demands.

Comment: More specifically, what features do you want to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your site already use Web Services?

In regards to Oracle UCM. All actions (check in/out, add, update, delete, etc) can all be controlled via webservices (wsdl's). WDSL is becoming pretty standard (at least in the Oracle space).

Adding support should allow you to create wrappers for multiple stores.

More info;

- http://www.w3schools.com/WSDL/default.asp
- http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at KnowledgeTree (http://www.knowledgetree.com).  It's open source, php core, and has built in Rest web service API's for easy connection.